# How can I detect when a TTreeViewItem node was expanded inside a TTreeView?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I have a `TTreeView` on a form, and it has a lot of `TTreeViewItem` nodes.

I would like to call some function only when the user *expands* one of the `TTreeViewItem` nodes (which does not necessarily mean the user "selected" one of the nodes).

I have tried catching this event with the following handlers:

```
TTreeView.OnChange
TTreeView.OnClick
TTreeView.OnMouseDown
TTreeViewItem.OnClick
TTreeViewItem.OnMouseDown
```

But none of these seem to be triggered when I only click the cute little arrow to the left of the expandable node.

Is there a way to be notified when the user *expands* a `TTreeViewItem`?

Comment: There is a private method `DoButtonClick` on a TTreeViewItem. You can try hooking into that.

Comment: It might be easier to simply re-assign the `TTreeViewItem.FButton.OnClick` event than to hook `TTreeViewItem.DoButtonClick()` directly. Or maybe there is a way to specify a custom object for the 'button' style resource? If so, you could try intercepting `StartTriggerAnimation('IsExpanded')` notifications sent to it by `TTreeViewItem`.

Comment: The TreeView of Firemonkey lacks of a functionality to report when a node is collapsed or expanded, but you can find a workaround on this article [Adding OnChangeExpanded Functionality to TTreeView](http://monkeystyler.com/blog/entry/adding-onchangeexpanded-functionality-to-ttreeview)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `TTreeView` and `TTreeViewItem` in FireMonkey do not expose any public events when nodes are expanded/collapsed.

The only thing I see are the private `TTreeViewItem.DoButtonClick()` event handler when the node's expand/collapse button is clicked, and `StartTriggerAnimation('IsExpanded')` notifications that are sent to that same button when the node's `IsExpanded` property changes value.

The actual button object is obtained from the `TTreeView`'s Style, so maybe there is a way to subclass that object so you can override `StartTriggerAnimation()`, or at least add a hidden child to it as the default `TFmxObject.StartTriggerAnimation()` implementation notifies child controls of the same trigger that is sent to the parent control.